# How can I get included objects in a contentful getEntry call using javascript sdk?

Tags: contentful

I see that I can pass a query object with `include:2` in the getEntries method using the node.js javascript api.  How can I do that with the `getEntry` call that returns a single object.

```
// how do I get the nested objects by passing the parameter include:1
client.getEntry('<entry_id>', {<what goes here?>})
.then(function (entry) {
  // logs the entry metadata

})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getEntry` returns 1 and only 1 entry. If you want to include the linked entries of 1 parent entry (aka more than one entry), you have to use the `getEntries` method and specify the `sys.id` of the parent entry you want to retrieve. Like so:

```
client.getEntries({'sys.id': '<entry_id>'})
.then(entries => {
  ...
})
```

Comment: UPDATE: as of [v7.0.0 of the Contentful.js](https://github.com/contentful/contentful.js) library, the `getEntry` function will also do link resolution. [See this for more details](https://github.com/contentful/contentful.js/blob/master/ADVANCED.md#link-resolution)